# Unsaved and uncommited changes still visible, even in new branch and local copy

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I'm working in a project (in azure devOps) and use git. For evey change, we need to use a subbranch and then merge it with the parent branch.

Revcently, I worked in a subbranch ("feature branch"), and made some big adjustment in the code. In the middle I got a new task and wanted to undo all changes. First thing I did, was to redo all changes. I did not commit anything during this,but instead redid every commit inside of VSC (did not commit anything). Closed my editor and deleted my subbranch. No commands and whatsoever in Git. Nothing was comitted or merged with the main branch.

I then made another subbranch from my main branch and I still get the changes I did in my other subbranch when I open it in VSC. Even if I did not commit, save, merge or anything else.

I did doublecheck my main branch (in devOps) and the changes are not there.But everytime I make a branch from this main branch, I get the unwanted changes even if it does NOT exist on the parent branch.

I then tried to delete my local installation of the branch and reinstall it. But the changes are still there when I make subbranch and open it in VSC. Very frustrating. Maybe its a problem with VSC. How to solve this?

Comment: Your workflow is confusing/not clear to me.  You might want to make it clear the exact Git steps which you took.

Comment: I have edit it my post. Hopefully its more clear now. In short - uncomitted and unmerged changes are still visible in my VSC, but not visbile even in the parent branch I work on.

Comment: Git does not have anything called a "subbranch". Git has branch names, like `master` or `develop`; such names identify one specific commit. There is not necessarily any relationship between any two branch names—all relationships in Git are between *commits*, which relate by ancestry ("X is the parent of Y", or "X is not the parent of Y") or a sort of "marriage" ("X and Y were combined via merge to produce Z").

Comment: While a branch name like `master` identifies one particular commit, the particular commit it does identify changes over time. The commits themselves *never* change: once commit X exists, it exists as commit X forever. The unique specifier that identifies commit X is its hash ID. The *name* `master` either holds `X`'s hash ID, or doesn't. If it doesn't, the *name* `master` holds some other hash ID. That other hash ID either has X as one of its parents or grandparents or some such, so that commit X is on branch `master`, or it doesn't, so that commit X is not on `master`. That's all Git has!

Comment: On the branch where you see changes you don't want, try `git log -p` and `git status`. It will tell you what the last changes on the branch are and how your sandbox differs from the branch, and hopefully help you understand what is happening. If it's a problem with VSC, then exploring your sandbox with command line tools will show you what's on your filesystem and the raw view Git has of things, and further help you troubleshoot things.

Comment: To `git log -p` and `git status`, add `git diff` and `git diff --cached`. And if you can't figure it out, the output of those commands might help you improve your question so someone else can.